# Importing es6 modules with a globbing patterns in browserify

Tags: javascript, import, module, ecmascript-6, browserify

I have a bunch of modules which I want to import into my main file (im working with browserify).

Now I have about 30 folders with modules in them, and it seems redundant to just type out every import for them. Let's assume for now that I don't know all the folder names in my packages folder.

So I was thinking about something like this:

```
import * as actions from '../packages/**/*.actions.js'
```

But this give me an error that it can't find any modules... I've looked at some implementations in combination with Systemjs, but this doesn't fit me well.

Comment: Are you using Babel or something to transpile the import statements to `require`? If so, you should be able to use https://github.com/capaj/require-globify

Comment: Gonna give that a try... thanks!

Comment: Note this is **not** a duplicate, this is specifically about the Browserify loader not about whether or not ES6 supports such functionality

Comment: Indeed, im really looking for a way to import my modules with knowing the exact folder name/structure.